# Question about smartgwt setIcon(String url)

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have image icons in the same directory in my project as the source file. From the source file I call button.setIcon("image.png"), or button.setIcon("/image.png") or button.setIcon("full/path/to/image.png")   but it does not display my image. My question is: how does Smart Gwt resolve url paths for images? I've looked at the documentation and this is not clear. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use successfully the following procedure to get images with SmartGWT working.

At the same level as the `client` package of your GWT module I create a folder named `public`. (In Eclipse you cannot create a package named `public` because this is not a valid package name. You have to create it explicitly as a folder.) This directory with name `public` is treated special by GWT. The GWT compiler copies all the included content to the resulting main module directory. So I usually create a subdirectory `images` under `public` and put all the images belonging to my GWT module in there.

For example:

```
com/stuff
    client
        Main.java
        ...
    public
        images
            a.png
            b.png
    mainmodule.gwt.xml
```

Then right at the beginning of the entry point I tell SmartGWT to look at the `images` subdirectory for the images (in this example is `mainmodule` the name of my main GWT module):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Page.setAppImgDir("[APP]/mainmodule/images/");
    ...
}
```

The `[APP]` part of the path is special SmartGWT syntax.

Later I am able to create an IButton like so:

```
final IButton aBtn = new IButton("A Button");
aBtn.setIcon("a.png");
```

Sometimes it is necessary to create the URL to an image not for SmartGWT but for plain GWT or plain HTML. For these cases you can create the URL with

```
final String bUrl = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "images/b.png";
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually came up with a workaround where I place the images in a folder img under war, then have an Ant build just copy it into my project with each build. Then I call the image files with  GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "images/b.png"; But your way is far more elegant! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can also reuse existing icons from theme. 
To use them try path `[SKIN]/{ComponentName}/image.png`
where `{ComponentName}` is one of existing folders in your theme or standard theme.

example:

```
node.setIcon("[SKIN]/TreeGrid/folder_open.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have helped this way.

1. Try to compile your project.
2. Find the folder in your project WAR: load-skin.js
3. Add the path in ModuleName.html to it after:

```js
<script>
     var isomorphicDir = "ModuleName/sc/";
</script>
```

For Example for my Project

```js
<!--load skin-->
<script src="/ModuleName/sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js"/>
```